# How to load html page by webview for full screen?

Tags: android, webview, fullscreen

When I load html code using webview , if the device is above android 5.0, the page load by webview is full screen without other settings, but if the device is below android 5.0 , the page cannot be full screen, why? How to solve this problem?

Comment: what you have tried! code please

Comment: when the page first load,if I wanna the page is as wide as screen, then I can enlarge the page through gestures, how should I do

Comment: book_intro_detail.loadDataWithBaseURL(Const.BASE_URL, good.goodsDesc, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);  good.goodsDesc is HTML code

Answer (score 0):

Try the following piece of code

```
//get the id     
WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
//set the following params as well
browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Comment: when the page first load,if I wanna the page is as wide as screen, then I can enlarge the page through gestures, how should I do